# Can a Linux process die by a mechanism other than a fatal signal or calling `exit(2)`?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

As far as I know, the only ways that the Linux kernel will clean up a process entry is if that process performs an `exit(2)` syscall or it fails to handle a fatal signal (like `SIGSEGV`, `SIGABRT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGKILL`, etc). I know that `SIGKILL` cannot be handled and so doesn't even actually get "delivered" to the process.. that's somewhat along the lines of what I'm thinking here.

Assuming the kernel itself stays intact and valid (not interested in hardware failure/device shutdown/panic/etc), are there *any* other ways a process can be destroyed?

Goal is to ensure coverage of a crash reporting framework - I'm pretty sure that fatal signals + `exit(2)` constitute the only ways I can die, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: That seems right to me. The only exception is if the system as a whole crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe you're correct that those are the only possibilities.

You can confirm this from the documentation of `wait(2)`. There are two related macros, `WIFEXITED()` and `WIFSIGNALED()` that can be used to determine why `wait` returned the given process. There are no other possibilities (I'm not counting `WIFSTOPPED()`, since it's used for detecting suspended processes, not processes that have terminated).

Actually, `exit(3)` is not a system call, it's a C library function. The system call is `_exit(2)`. `exit(3)` performs some C cleanup (e.g. flushing `stdio` buffers and calling `atexit()` functions) and then calls `_exit(2)` to actually exit the process.